# Varnish and additional ports

Tags: apache, port, varnish

How can I add another port to Apache, and keep Varnish listening on port 80 only? The other new port would have a different document root.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache's `sites-available` configuration files you can specify what port the configured name should resolve on.